# Elisp equivalent of FUNCTION-LAMBDA-EXPRESSION?

Tags: symbol-function

In Common Lisp, there is a function called `function-lambda-expression`, which returns the LAMBDA form that defines a function (or `NIL` on implementations that compile everything to native code).

Is there a function in ELisp that does something similar?

Comment: `symbol-function` returns the actual function object for the argument symbol, which will then be displayed as its printed representation (either a lambda form or compiled byte-code, but you could load the uncompiled version of the library to avoid the latter). Is that the sort of thing you're after?

Comment: @phils `symbol-function` can also (and will often) return an auto-load. That is the reason I hesitated to post a comment similar to yours.

Comment: True. Or a symbol, if function indirection is happening. Or just whatever was jammed into the function cell for the symbol, really.

Comment: You would need to follow the `describe-function` code to see how does it get the arguments of a function. I think it parses source code to do that (i.e. symbols have references to the location they are declared in). This isn't bulletproof, since functions declared by macros, who don't have a symbol assigned to them would pose a problem.

Comment: All these comments are good. Someone please consider consolidating them (or similar) into an answer. It's a good question, even if the answer might not be entirely satisfying.

Comment: @phils, `symbol-function` is what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`symbol-function` can return an actual function object for the
argument symbol, which would be displayed as its printed
representation (either a lambda form or compiled byte-code -- but
you could load the uncompiled version of the library to avoid the
latter).

More precisely, it returns the value of the symbol's function
cell. Besides a function object, other common values are:

- auto-load objects: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Autoload Type`
- symbols: `(elisp) Function Indirection`
- keyboard macros: `(elisp) Keyboard Macros`

(Strictly speaking, I believe a function cell can contain *any* value,
but some types are rather more expected than others.)

Comment: Are there opaque compiled function objects in Elisp, other than for those functions that are written in C?

Comment: I don't think so. AFAIK the only options are `(elisp) Primitive Function Type` (in C), and normal lisp functions (which are all ultimately lambdas).